# Contact Form 7 Custom module

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I am using a custom post type name `venue` and I am using a `<select>` dropdown on one of the contact form by loading up a custom module in CF7 but when the form is submitted, my data shortcode is not replaced with the data filled by the user.

I just see this `[selected-venue]`. Here is my code for custom module:

```
<?php

wpcf7_add_shortcode( 'party-venue', 'wpcf7_venue_shortcode_handler', true );

function wpcf7_venue_shortcode_handler( $tag ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts} where post_type = 'venue' and post_status = 'publish';";

    $result = $wpdb->get_col( $query );

    if ( $result ) {
        $output = '<select name="contact_venue" id="contact_venue" class="input-select">';
        $output.= '<option></option>';
        foreach ( $result as $venue ) {
            $output.= '<option value="'.$venue.'">'.$venue.'</option>';
        }
        $output.= '</select>';
    }

    return $output;
}
```

My contact form's code is

```
<label for="contact_name"><span class="large_contact">name</span><span class="small_contact">Please enter your full name</span></label>[text* your-name class:input-textarea] 
<label for="contact_email"><span class="large_contact">email</span><span class="small_contact">Please enter a valid email address</span></label>[email* your-email class:input-textarea]
<label for="contact_phone"><span class="large_contact">phone</span><span class="small_contact">Please enter a phone number to reach you at</span></label>[text phone class:input-textarea]
<label for="contact_friends"><span class="large_contact">party size</span><span class="small_contact">*Min 50 guests for free bottle, 15 guests for buy 1 bottle get 1 free*</span></label>[text party-size class:input-textarea] </p>
<label for="contact_venue"><span class="large_contact">venue</span><span class="small_contact">Please select your party venue</span></label>[party-venue selected-venue id:contact_venue]
<label for="contact_date"><span class="large_contact">date</span><span class="small_contact">Please enter your party date (mm/dd/yy)</span></label>[text date id:contact_date class:input-textarea]
<label for="referal_source"><span class="large_contact">How did you hear about us?</span><span class="small_contact">Please select one of the options</span></label>[select menu-367 class:input-select "" "CitySearch" "Facebook" "Facebook Ad" "Friend" "Google Search" "NYC Daily Deals" "Yelp"]

[submit class:input-submit]
```

And here is my message body:

```
From: [your-name] <[your-email]>
Subject: Book a party!

Message Body:
Phone: [phone], 
Party Size: [party-size], 
Venue: [selected-venue], 
Date: [date]
How did you hear about us: [menu-367]
```

When I get the email on form submission, `[selected-venue]` is not replaced with the actual value of the select dropdown. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name of the input field should match with the filler shortcode so that it returns data.
I changed
`$output = '<select name="contact_venue"` to `$output = '<select name="selected-venue"` and it works now.